# What can produce slow down of mariadb

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

Our Mariadb database (1To) encounter slow down during some minutes but we don't find the root cause : there no CPU or IO overhead but locks OS dans lot of process taking time on sending data and statistics.

This happen one time day not at same hour.

[image]

Update 1 :
There are lot a slow query during the slow down not easy to find the one that cause that.
Slow query graph :

[image]

Update 2 :
When we SHOW PROCESS list we see lot of queries in "sending data", all query are different, it seems to be normal query that are slow for some minutes.

Update 3 :
I found in InnoDB Status a long transaction running, I believe that can be the root cause :
[image]

Comment: I'd enable the slow query log. It looks like a odd query doing a large amount of data fetching and should show up pretty clearly when it does occur.

Comment: Is that on a Cloud service?  When are backups performed?  "1To" is a lot of "Sending data".  Next time it happens, connect as root and capture `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`.

Comment: If you don't see much in the slowlog, lower `long_query_time` from its nearly-useless 10 second default.

Comment: Yes long_quert_time is setup to 10 sec. Because we thought that there ware a bottleneck in slowquerylog file.

Comment: No backup was performed, there is a replicat for that.

Comment: Definitely lower long_query_time. You can change it with something like `SET GLOBAL long_query_time=0.5;` Do you have other processes running on the same server outside of MariaDB? By the way, replication is not a substitute for backups!

Comment: We do backups on replicat. I can change long_query but server handle 15k QPS so I'll add log_slow_rate_limit to throttle slowquery rate. That'is not the same usage to me.

Comment: Other process is PMM agent.

Comment: Well done on finding your log update query. Is this frequently executed? Are the indexes appropriate for it? What does `explain {query}` show for it?